# To replace a place by coordinates

Tags: java, android

I try of creating an app that shows me distance and duration travel from my current location and another point, I work with the below code, and I need to replace the origin by my current location and destination by any point but in coordinates.

How I can modify this code, for to log rate the functions described

This is my ActivityMain

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        btnFindPath = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFindPath);
        etOrigin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOrigin);
        etDestination = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDestination);

        btnFindPath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendRequest();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendRequest() {
        String origin = etOrigin.getText().toString();
        String destination = etDestination.getText().toString();
        if (origin.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter origin address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (destination.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter destination address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            new DirectionFinder(this, origin, destination).execute();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng hcmus = new LatLng(10.762963, 106.682394);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(hcmus, 18));
        originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Đại học Khoa học tự nhiên")
                .position(hcmus)));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDirectionFinderStart() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait.",
                "Finding direction..!", true);

        if (originMarkers != null) {
            for (Marker marker : originMarkers) {
                marker.remove();
            }
        }

        if (destinationMarkers != null) {
            for (Marker marker : destinationMarkers) {
                marker.remove();
            }
        }

        if (polylinePaths != null) {
            for (Polyline polyline:polylinePaths ) {
                polyline.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDirectionFinderSuccess(List<Route> routes) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
        originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
        destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Route route : routes) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(route.startLocation, 16));
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDuration)).setText(route.duration.text);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDistance)).setText(route.distance.text);

            originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue))
                    .title(route.startAddress)
                    .position(route.startLocation)));
            destinationMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green))
                    .title(route.endAddress)
                    .position(route.endLocation)));

            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().
                    geodesic(true).
                    color(Color.BLUE).
                    width(10);

            for (int i = 0; i < route.points.size(); i++)
                polylineOptions.add(route.points.get(i));

            polylinePaths.add(mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get current location by using fused location

```
Task locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                    mLastKnownLocation = task.getResult();
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                                    mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mDefaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

for further detail check the link below

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/current-place-tutorial